# Moving a shape based upon screen width

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to make two dice roll across a screen, Hit a wall, bounce back, and come to rest.
What I would like is to have the wall placed based upon the dimension of the screen.
I have no idea have to get that info out of excel.

```
Sub Roll_Dice()
Dim leftDieRotation As Single, rightDieRotation As Single, leftDieMovement As Single, rightDieMovement As Single
Dim wsCraps As Worksheet

Set wsCraps = Sheets("Craps")
   
With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
   .Left = 500
   .Top = 80
End With
    
 With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39"))
    .Left = 500
    .Top = 180
 End With
 
For x = 1 To 50
   Randomize
   leftDieRotation = Int(10 + Rnd * 25)
   leftDieMovement = Int(2 + Rnd * 25)
   rightDieRotation = Int(10 + Rnd * 25)
   rightDieMovement = Int(2 + Rnd * 25)
    
    With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
    .IncrementRotation leftDieRotation
    .IncrementLeft leftDieMovement
    End With
    
   With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39"))
    .IncrementRotation rightDieRotation
    .IncrementLeft rightDieMovement
    End With

Sheets("dice").Range("a1") = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
Sheets("dice").Range("e1") = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
DoEvents
Next x

' move dice to center
Do While wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38")).Left >= 700
    With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
    .IncrementLeft -15
    End With
     With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39"))
    .IncrementLeft -9
    DoEvents
    End With
Loop
Do While wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38")).Top <= 180
    With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
    .IncrementTop 15
    End With
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Currently, the two dice just move random amounts for 50 counts and come to a rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a piece of code whitch change the ChartObjects position and dimentions in a sheet maybe help:

```
Public Const SM_CXVSCROLL = 2
Public Sub example(aname As String)
   Dim oChart As ChartObject, w As Double, h As Double, r As Range
   
   w = Application.ActiveWindow.Width
   h = Application.ActiveWindow.Height
   For Each oChart In Me.ChartObjects
      If Left(oChart.Name, 5) = "GRAPH" Then
         With oChart
            .Top = 20
            .Left = 8
            .Width = Application.Width - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) - 22 - IIf(ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings, 20, 0)
            '.Width = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) - 22 - IIf(ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings, 20, 0)
            .Height = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height - (4 * Range("CUR_GRAPH").Height) - 100
         End With
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```